# How to get all documents per topic in bertopic modeling

Tags: nlp, text-classification, bert-language-model, topic-modeling

I have a dataset and trying to convert it to topics using berTopic modeling but the problem is,  i cant get all the docoments of a topic. berTopic is only return 3 docoments per topic.

```
topic_model  = BERTopic(verbose=True, embedding_model=embedding_model,
                                nr_topics = 'auto',
                                n_gram_range = (3,3),
                                top_n_words = 10,
                               calculate_probabilities=True, 
                              seed_topic_list = topic_list,
                              )
topics, probs = topic_model.fit_transform(docs_test)
representative_doc = topic_model.get_representative_docs(topic#1)
representative_doc
```

[this topic contain more then 300 documents but bertopic only shows 3 of them with `.get_representative_docs`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqjRd.png)

Answer (score 8):

There are probably solutions that are more elegant because I am not an expert, but I can share what worked for me:

```
topics, probs = topic_model.fit_transform(docs_test)
```

returns the topics.

Therefore, you can combine this output and the documents.
For example, combine them into a Pandas dataframe using:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'topic': topics, 'document': docs_test})
```

Now, you can filter this dataframe for each topic to identify the referring documents:

```
topic_0 = df[df.topic == 0]
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an API from BERTopic `get_document_info()` which returns the dataframe for each document and associated topic for it. https://maartengr.github.io/BERTopic/api/bertopic.html#bertopic._bertopic.BERTopic.get_document_info

The response from this API is shown below:

| index | Document | Topic | Name | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | doc1_text | 241 | kw1_kw2_ | ... |
| 1 | doc2_text | -1 | kw1_kw2_ | ... |

You can use this dataframe to get all the documents associated for a particular topic using pandas groupby or however you prefer.

```py
T = topic_model.get_document_info(docs)
docs_per_topics = T.groupby(["Topic"]).apply(lambda x: x.index).to_dict()
```

The code returns a dictionary shown as below:

```
{
    -1: Int64Index([3,10,11,12,15,16,18,19,20,22,...365000], dtype='int64',length=149232),
    0: Int64Index([907,1281,1335,1337,...308420,308560,308645],dtype='int64',length=5127),
    ...
}
```

Comment: it was when bertopic don't have any API, earlier version of it was having this problem now it is quite easy.